# Adding functionality to all subclasses of UIViewController

Tags: objective-c

Here is my situation and I'm confused as to the best way to do this (SubClass,Category,Extension, just write it in all the classes I want).  I want to basically add a managedObjectContext to a bunch of my view controllers and have it passed around.  I've had to add the following code to a majority of my controllers and I realize there is probably an easier way to do this:

**Header Files:**

```
@interface
@property(weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@end
```

**.m files**:

```
// Synthesize the variable
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

and

```
// Pass on managedObjectContext
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    // If the destination VC is able to take teh setManagedObjectContext method the current objectContext will be passed along.
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)
                                              withObject:self.managedObjectContext];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"Segue to controller [%@] that does not support passing managedObjectContext", [segue destinationViewController]);
    }
}
@end
```

So here is where the question is:  I have

- UIViewControllers
- UITableViewControllers
- Probably-another-uiController

What is the best method of adding these functions to my class?

As a side not, however, I do want my class to be able to add additional methods to the **prepareForSegue** call which makes me think perhaps subClassing things would be best.  That way in my individual class implementation i can call `[super prepareForSegue...]`.  That begin said, however, I assume I'd have to make a single class per view controller because you can't do multiple inheritance or have I managed to confuse myself?

-- EDIT --

Various Comments have suggested a Category is the right way to go, however, if I make a category for **prepareForSegue** am I still able to make a call somehow equivalent to **[categoryVersion prepareForSegue]** I realize I could probably use a different function name but I do want to modify the default functionality of prepareForSegue

Comment: I am thinking why haven't you made use of category on UIViewController as you can put all your code in that particular category and that will solve your problem of multiple inheritance as well.

Comment: @Nitni You can't add a property to a category.

Comment: Here you go http://kaspermunck.github.io/2012/11/adding-properties-to-objective-c-categories/

Comment: You can add a property to category's interface however you cannot use @synthesize in its implementation however you can always define your own getter and setter which is what property actually is :)

Comment: One more example showing how to use property in category http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/12/Adding-Properties-to-an-Objective-C-Category.html

Comment: @Nitni How do i deal with the same function definition in the category?  I might want to do other things in prepareForSegue of the base class

Comment: @Nitni You are correct -- let me rephrase, you _shouldn't_, not can't.

Comment: @Jeef I am sorry but I can't get you why you want to make other function with same definition?